# How do you change starting day of the week wtih Flatpickr?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flatpickr

I want to set my language and change the starting date. The application is in React.

```
<Flatpickr
className="form-control cdr-filter-input-flatpickr"
name="date"
value={date}
options={options}
onChange={date => {event}
/>
```

And the options:

```
const options = {
locale:{
    ...'fr',
    firstDayOfWeek:3
},
dateFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i',
time_24hr: true,
};
```

What does it do? It doesn't set the language to French but it does set the starting date correctly.
If I do `"locale:'fr'"`, I cannot modify the `firstDayOfWeek` anymore.

According to https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr/issues/1398, it should work. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it. It had a few problems, @Bharath set me on the correct way to figure it out.

I had to change

```
import 'flatpickr/dist/l10n/';
```

to

```
import {English} from  'flatpickr/dist/l10n/default.js';
import {Dutch} from  'flatpickr/dist/l10n/nl.js';
import {French} from  'flatpickr/dist/l10n/fr.js';
```

These has to be written in the same way as index.js file in `\node_modules\flatpickr\dist\l10n`. Somewhere at the bottom, they declare var l10n = {...} around line 3529. So look for that.

Then I had to write a `switch case` to set my locale settings correctly. I ended up doing this in an helper file

```
let options = {
  //do your own settings
}
switch(lang)
{
  case "en":
    options.locale={
      ...English,
      firstDayOfWeek:startingDay
    }
    break;
  ...
}
```

and then:

```
<Flatpickr
className="form-control cdr-filter-input-flatpickr"
name="date"
value={date}
options={options}
onChange={date => {event}
/>
```

Comment: As a side note: `import {English} from  'flatpickr/dist/l10n/default.js';` didn't work for me: I could import it but for some reason ist content was `undefined`. I solved the issue by importing all available languages via `import FlatpickrLanguages from "flatpickr/dist/l10n";` and then setting the locale like `locale: {
     ...FlatpickrLanguages['xx']
}`, where the 2 x's are the 2 language code letters. (check https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr/issues/1342#issuecomment-397987165)

Answer (score 1):

imported the language

```
import { French } from "flatpickr/dist/l10n/fr.js";
```

Now passing it to options

```
locale: {
   ...French,
   firstDayOfWeek: 3,
},
```

working demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-flatpickr-example-not-working-v4rijc?file=src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used 'import "flatpickr/dist/l10n/"' since I needed most of those languages. How do I then dynamically access those variables?